# pyqt string to a normal python string is giving some text appends to the string

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4

When I try to print a PyQT string, it is not converted to a normal string. How can I do it? See the code below.

```
    def _execute_test(self):
        test_in = str(self.buildFlags.inFlags)
        test_out = str(self.buildFlags.exFlags)
        print(str(test_in))
        print("============")
        print(str(test_out))
```

The output I get is:

```
>>> [PyQt4.QtCore.QString(u'Documents'), PyQt4.QtCore.QString(u'New folder')]
```

Comment: Are you printing a list of QStrings ?

Comment: i want to print in normal string but the casting str() did not work ???
i want a list = ['Documents', 'New folder']

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to print a list of string from a list of PyQt4.QtCore.QString try this:

```
print([str(x) for x in my_qstring_list])
```